How to get LinkedIn API via Python to work so I get number of followers?
Problem statement:
Using linkedin API in python I need to get number of followers and impressions.
My Approach:
I am added to my company's linkedIn page as a contributor. I created an app via developer.linkedin which is connected to the company's linkedIn page. Got following scopes for this app:

r_organization_followers
r_organization_social
rw_organization_admin
r_organization_social_feed

import requests
import urllib.parse

#  Obtain Authorization Code 
client_id = 'ABC'
client_secret = 'XYZ'

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080'  # for my local machine testing

scope = 'r_organization_social rw_organization_admin'

encoded_scope = urllib.parse.quote(scope)
auth_url = f'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope={encoded_scope}'
print(f'Go to the following URL to authorize the app: {auth_url}')

I use this to get the access token and call it "authorization_code". Also using "CompanyName" as my company name in the URL
token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'
data = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': authorization_code,
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret
}

response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
print(f'Access Token: {access_token}')

#Get Organization ID: 
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
    'LinkedIn-Version': '202406'
}

org_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizations?q=vanityName&vanityName=CompanyName'
org_response = requests.get(org_url, headers=headers)
org_data = org_response.json()
organization_id = org_data['elements'][0]['id']
print(f'Organization ID: {organization_id}')

Until here I get all the outputs correctly. However, when I try to get the followers data, I am getting hit with 500, internal service error. And this is for the last 1 week. I am convinced I am not doing something right here.
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
    'LinkedIn-Version': '202406'
}
# Get the number of followers
followers_url = f'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity={organization_id}'
followers_response = requests.get(followers_url, headers=headers)
followers_response.json()

I have tried with various LinkedIn-Versions, like 202408 or 202402, either the response is the version is outdated or Internal server error.
Any pointers?

What value are you passing for the organizationalEntity? It needs to be a URN of the form urn:li:organization:{id}.

organization_id that I get from penultimate part of the code

You need to pass the URN in the given format, not just a plain integer ID.

That solved the problem. Thank you
